# Sorting content of a text file in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I would like to sort a text file which contains
lines like

```
1000S 00RR: 20 values
1200S -10RR: 10 values
900S -20RR: 6 values
150S -05RR: 4 values
10000S 00RR: 2 values
```

I want to sort it as (in the order ascending taking the first element before space's numerical value into consideration)

```
150S -05RR: 4 values
900S -20RR: 6 values
1000S 00RR: 20 values
1200S -10RR: 10 values
10000S 00RR: 2 values
```

I was wondering what would be the better way to implement it.

I tried the following:

```
with open(file_name, "r") as file_name_opened:
    lines = file_name_opened.readlines()
    for x in range(0,20):
        try:
            list_one.append(lines[x])
        except IndexError:
            pass

return sorted(list_one)
print("sorted: " + str(sorted(list_one)))
```

It would be nice to know if there is a better way to do it...

Comment: Have you tried *any* way to implement it? Is efficiency a problem with your current code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added the implementation I did for this....

Comment: So does that work? Is it inefficient (have you had a performance problem, and done any profiling to find out where)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An open file is an iterable of strings that end with '\n'.  While developing code to process an open file as such an iterable, one can instead define such an iterable in the code itself.  This can be done with a multiline string literal and `splitlines`, as shown below.  This makes it possible to post code that readers can execute themselves without the bother of creating and later deleting a separate file.

The key problem in sorting is to define the key function.  Based on your example, you want the integer value of each line up to the 'S'.  So you need to fine the 'S', split out the preceding digits, and convert the number substring to an int.

```
data = '''\
1000S 00RR: 20 values
1200S -10RR: 10 values
900S -20RR: 6 values
150S -05RR: 4 values
10000S 00RR: 2 values
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)

def keyfunc(line):
    return int(line[:line.index('S')])
test_int = keyfunc("1000S 00RR: 20 values")  # for testing only
print(type(test_int), test_int)
# <class 'int'> 1000

out = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
for line in out: print(line, end='')
```

This code prints the output you requested.  To use it with a file, delete the `data` and `keyfunc` test statements and wrap the `sorted` statement with `with open(filename) as data:`

Comment: Thanks a lot that's very valid information.... It helped me to understand the concept better !